# Resolve host name from IP address

Tags: windows, networking, command-line-interface

I'm looking for a command line tool which gets an IP address and returns the host name, for Windows.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/q/366613/2321

Answer (score 169, accepted):

The command you are looking for is called `nslookup`, works fine for reverse lookups **IFF** someone has configured a reverse zone file, which they don't always do.

Answer (score 120):

if all the above fails, and you are specifically looking for a Windows machine, you can use

```
nbtstat -a 192.168.1.50
```

The data returned will be all the NetBIOS records the machine has. The one with a <20h> record type will usually be the machine's name.

Comment: Not working when connected through the open vpn

Comment: @Flextra - you will need SMB access to the machine. Your VPN may be blocking it.

Comment: Interesting, looks like it tacks on the fully qualified domain name in the formatting: `Pinging NETBIOSNAME.DOMAINNAME.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]`. If its on the network and not on the domain (for me a unix system of interest) then `ping -a` just formats with the ipaddress alone it looks like.

Comment: Works for me. Just what I needed!

Comment: I keep getting `Host not found.` any idea why?

Comment: I think it doesn't work on Windows 10, I keep getting, `Host not found.`.

Comment: It does work on Windows 10, but on the target machine, the windows 10 firewall must not be blocking smb, and the Server service must be running to get the <20h> record.

Answer (score 84):

For many IP addresses you could just use ping -a, for example

```
ping -a 209.85.229.106
```

will return

```
Pinging ww-in-f106.google.com [209.85.229.106] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 209.85.229.106...........
```

Comment: This is what I always use first as it is universally available on pretty much every machine.

Comment: ping is sooo often used to do simple DNS lookups... *sigh* don't do that.

Comment: this is the only answer that got me the hostname from my raspberry in my LAN. @PEra why is this a bad answer?

Comment: How does this works? Though which protocol?

Answer (score 36):

If you use nslookup command with the IP address as its first argument will return the PTR record (the reverse entry) if it exists.  For example:

```
nslookup 192.168.1.50
```

Answer (score 3):

Use dig.  A Windows port is available from the ISC [**here**](https://www.isc.org/software/bind) (look in the immediate download box for the link to the zip file).  Here's their [**man page reference for dig**](https://www.isc.org/software/bind/documentation/arm95#man.dig).

[Ward's point](https://serverfault.com/a/74044/409628) about the reverse lookup records often not getting created is very much true.  Reverse lookups often do fail because many admins don't bother creating the ptr records.

Answer (score 3):

(tested under Windows 10 x64)

**From command line:**

`FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %A in ('2^>NUL NSLOOKUP "%IP_ADDRESS%" ^| FINDSTR /C:":    "') do ECHO %A`

**Within a script:**

`FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= " %%A in ('2^>NUL NSLOOKUP "%IP_ADDRESS%" ^| FINDSTR /C:":    "') do ECHO %%A`

**Two (side)notes:**

- To supress `NSLOOKUP` errors you have to use `2^>NUL` instead of `1^>NUL`
- I've used `FINDSTR /C` to extract the value after the four whitespace characters. As the four spaces only seem to exist for the `Name:` entry, this appears to be only way to make it work on other localized systems.

Answer (score 1):

`tracert` might be an option.

`tracert 10.12.190.51`

Results in:

```
Tracing route to LAP8662.aus.int.example.com [10.12.190.51]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  LAP8662.aus.int.example.com [10.12.190.51]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: This just uses the reverse DNS, it is exactly the same as using nslookup. But in this case the name resolution is a side effect and you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks Nikita. The curious thing is that sometimes `tracert` returns the resolved name, but `nslookup` doesn't. It must be some peculiarity about my network setup.

Comment: This is the statement I wouldn't believe unless I see it myself ;) The explanation must be that nslookup uses only DNS protocol, but tracert uses the system name resolution library which uses DNS as a last resort, after WINS, NetBIOS, hosts file and so on were tried; however, in your example the name looks like DNS name. Anyway, I wouldn't rely on the results that all those "automatic" methods produce.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know the host-name in same network then please use another machine which have same network and use below commend
Ping -an ip addres

Comment: Didn't you notice this answer was already here? – and it's not designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

psexec \192.168.0.65 hostname

**DMHD006**
hostname exited on 192.168.0.65 with error code 0.

Comment: Keep in mind that the configured hostname not necessarily matches the hostname that is configured in DNS.